# How to make capturing output from an external process thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, groovy, process, gpars

I've written a small method to execute the `git` command line tool and capture its output:

```
def git(String command) {
    command = "git ${command}"

    def outputStream = new StringBuilder()
    def errorStream = new StringBuilder()
    def process = command.execute()
    process.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, errorStream)

    return [process.exitValue(), outputStream, errorStream, command]
}
```

I'm using it with GPars to clone multiple repositories simultaneously like

```
GParsPool.withPool(10) {
    repos.eachParallel { cloneUrl, cloneDir->
        (exit, out, err, cmd) = git("clone ${cloneUrl} ${cloneDir}")
        if (exit != 0) {
            println "Error: ${cmd} failed with '${errorStream}'."
        }
    }
}
```

However, I believe my `git` method it not thread-safe: For example, a second thread could modify `command` in the first line of the method before the first thread reached `command.execute()` in the fifth line of the method.

I could solve this by making the whole `git` method `synchronized`, but that would defeat the purpose of running it in different threads as I want clones to happen in parallel.

So I was thinking to do partial synchronization like

```
def git(String command) {
    def outputStream
    def errorStream
    def process

    synchronized {
        command = "git ${command}"

        outputStream = new StringBuilder()
        errorStream = new StringBuilder()
        process = command.execute()
    }

    process.waitForProcessOutput(outputStream, errorStream)

    return [process.exitValue(), outputStream, errorStream, command]
}
```

But I guess that also is not safe as in thread two `waitForProcessOutput()` might return earlier than in thread one, screwing up the `outputStream` / `errorStream` variables.

What is the correct way to get this thread-safe?

Comment: race conditions within the method are not a problem, since each method invocation gets its own stack frame for parameters and local variables. HOWEVER, at the point of return there is no such guarantee. Yo do not show how your variables `exit`, `out`, `err`, and `cmd` are declared, but however they are declared they are likely to be continually overwritten in random order as parallel executions of the `git()` method complete.

Comment: Furthermore, the argument `command` is not actually shared across invocations either, since it is generated (and hence instantiated) from interpolated values with each invocation. Furthermore, you are not modifying the `command` string, because strings are immutable; you are replacing the original `command` string with a new one. You are just replacing the value of the `command` variable with a new string object. The old string object that was passed in remains unchanged and hence cannot be the cause of a race condition.

Comment: FYI, the `exit`, `out`, `err`, and `cmd` are not declared anywhere, I'm literally using the code as shown. To be honest, I was also surprised to see it working without `def`ing these variables, but it simply does work. So bottom line, are you saying my code is fine as-is, there is no race conditions?

Comment: No, I am saying the race conditions all occur at the assignment statement inside the `eachParallel` closure argument (in your 2nd block of code). AS FAR AS I CAN TELL there are no race conditions inside your `git()` method, so your rewrite (3rd block of code) doesn't solve anything.

Comment: I was assuming that each variable declared inside `eachParallel` is a thread-local variable. I was further assuming that `(exit, out, err, cmd) =` implies the declaration of these variables. If these assumptions are correct there should be no problem, or?

Comment: No, the declaration of these variables must be either implicit in the binding under which the script is running, or you need to declare them with `def`, A single `def` in front of the statement would suffice to make them local (not "thread local", but invocation-local, which effectively makes them thread-safe. However, it also makes them inaccessible outside the invocation, which is probably not your intent.

Comment: Do you want to accumulate lists of these 4 properties and somehow combine/summarize them after the parallel invocation? Right now you are just overwriting them randomly as each successive parallel invocation completes.

Comment: No, I don't want to accumulate globally, but just handle these variables immediately after the `git` invocation. I've edited the code to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks. If you don't mind putting your last comment into an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: One more thing, though: Do you know why `(exit, out, err, cmd) =` even works without having a `def` in front of it?

Comment: Re "why does `(...) =` even work": It turns out that when you reference undeclared variables in a Groovy script, Groovy treats them as  "script-global" variables (members of the script's "binding" map). Because they are effectively global, they are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the assignment statement inside the `eachParallel` closure argument as follows:

```
        def (exit, out, err, cmd) = git("clone ${cloneUrl} ${cloneDir}")
```

This will make the variables local to the closure, which in turn will make them thread-safe. The `git()` method is fine as is.